# Understanding prime number generator

Tags: algorithm, erlang, primes

[This site](http://wbear.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/prime-numbers-with-erlang/) shows a function that generate a list of prime numbers.

```
-module(eratosthenes).
-export([prime_numbers/1]).

% Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm for finding all prime numbers up to N.
% http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

% Generate list of prime numbers up to N.
prime_numbers(N) when is_number(N) ->
prime_numbers(N, generate(N)).

prime_numbers(Max, [H|T]) when H * H =< Max ->
   [H | prime_numbers(Max, [R || R <- T, (R rem H) > 0])];

prime_numbers(_, T) -> T.

% Generate sequence 2..N
generate(N) -> generate(N, 2).

generate(Max, Max) -> [Max];

generate(Max, X) -> [X | generate(Max, X + 1)].
```

I did not understand the function at:

```
prime_numbers(_, T) -> T.
```

I did this example using a pen and paper:

```
prime_numbers(5)

1 - prime_numbers(5, [2,3,4,5])
2 - [2 | prime_numbers(5, [R || R <- [3,4,5], (R rem H) > 0)]
3 - [2 | prime_numbers(5, [3,5])]

prime_numbers(5, [3,5])

H * H =< MAX

3*3 =< 5 (False)

prime_numbers(_, T) -> T.

H = 3
T = 5

prime_numbers(5, [3,5]) = [5]

resp: [2,5]


or prime_numbers(5, [3,5]) = [3|[5]]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Also, T = [3, 5] in your example,  so the output is correct

Comment: `prime_numbers(5, [3,5])`

`H * H =< MAX`

`3*3 =< 5 (False)`

`prime_numbers(_, T) -> T.` --- at which point `T = [3,5]`, there's no deconstructing it into `H` and `T` in this clause. So, `prime_numbers(5, [3,5]) -> [3,5]`.

Comment: and of course, since it filters numbers out by trial division (`mod`) this is ***not*** the sieve of Eratosthenes. This is a bounded (i.e. with top limit value) optimal (since it stops at the sqrt) trial division sieve.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this, you must look at the whole function:

```
prime_numbers(Max, [H|T]) when H * H =< Max ->
   [H | prime_numbers(Max, [R || R <- T, (R rem H) > 0])];
prime_numbers(_, T) -> T.
```

I have removed a newline since it doesn't really apply in this case. The idiom in Erlang is to keep *clauses* for a function together like this. Note that this function has two clauses. We *pattern match* against them<sup>[0]</sup>. So this reads:

"Suppose we are given something named `Max` and a list of at least one element with `[H|T]`. Deconstruct the list into the head element `H` and the rest of the list `T`. Now, this pattern has a `when` guard so it only applies if `H*H =< Max`.

If this doesn't match, say if the `when` guard is wrong or we are given an empty list `[]`, then we try to match against the next clause, `(_, T)`. This one always matches and throws away the first parameter (`_`). It then matches whatever is in the 2nd parameter and binds it to `T`. Then it runs its body."

The key to understanding this is to understand pattern matches. Once you grasp those, the code should be clear and easy to read.

<sup>[0]</sup> Look up the concept of pattern matching. It is central to many languages like Prolog, ML, Haskell, Erlang, ...

Comment: I think you should point out at which point OPs trace is wrong

Comment: ok, but what is happening when we have the case prime_numbers(5,[3,5])?